# summing up certain rows in a panda dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 1000 rows and 10 columns. I am looking to aggregate rows 100-1000 and replace them with just one row where the indexvalue is '>100' and the column values are the sum of rows 100-1000 of each column. Any ideas on a simple way of doing this? Thanks in advance

Say I have the below

```
     a    b    c
0    1    10   100
1    2    20   100
2    3    60   100
3    5    80   100
```

and I want it replaced with

```
     a    b    c
0    1    10   100
1    2    20   100
>1   8    140  200
```

Comment: Could you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: sure, just added it to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`ix`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwix0oDyu-fKAhWGjSwKHQbiAyUQFggkMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.DataFrame.ix.html&usg=AFQjCNFymwgjauhaSAlqoFjWmEzxkiL__Q) or [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) but it shows `SettingWithCopyWarning`:

```
ind = 1
mask = df.index > ind
df1 = df[~mask]
df1.ix['>1', :] = df[mask].sum()

In [69]: df1
Out[69]:
    a    b    c
0   1   10  100
1   2   20  100
>1  8  140  200
```

To set it without warning you could do it with [`pd.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html). May be not elegant due to two transposing but worked:

```
ind = 1
mask = df.index > ind
df1 = pd.concat([df[~mask].T, df[mask].sum()], axis=1).T
df1.index = df1.index.tolist()[:-1] + ['>{}'.format(ind)]

In [36]: df1
Out[36]:
    a    b    c
0   1   10  100
1   2   20  100
>1  8  140  200
```

Some demonstrations:

```
In [37]: df.index > ind
Out[37]: array([False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [38]: df[mask].sum()
Out[38]:
a      8
b    140
c    200
dtype: int64

In [40]: pd.concat([df[~mask].T, df[mask].sum()], axis=1).T
Out[40]:
   a    b    c
0  1   10  100
1  2   20  100
0  8  140  200
```